# is it possible to make ionic android platform open into android studio and make expansion APK

Tags: android, ionic2, expansion, apk-expansion-files

I need to compress my ionic android platform assets folder. I already used a plugin for the APK expansion but the APK is working very slow with the plugin

this is the new plugin which I am facing slow/stuck in the APK

```
https://github.com/erobertson42/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/tree/cordova-9
```

But now I am thinking about the ionic platform code will open in Android studio and there I can do the Expansion process. I have already used the official Android doc for the expansion but the file is not generating with my Ionic Android platform code

```
https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files
```